# Map abstract type in Kotlin with MapStruct

Tags: kotlin, gradle, mapstruct

I'm trying to map an abstract class with Mapstruct in Kotlin, but getting the following error:

```
AnimalMapper.java: error: The return type AnimalOutput is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.
```

My implementation:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")
interface AnimalMapper {

    fun mapToDogOutput(dogInput: DogInput): DogOutput

    fun mapToCatOutput(catInput: CatInput): CatOutput

    fun mapToAnimalOutput(animalInput: AnimalInput): AnimalOutput {
        when (animalInput) {
            is DogInput -> mapToDogOutput(animalInput)
            is CatInput -> mapToCatOutput(animalInput)
        }
        throw RuntimeException("Unsupported animal type");
    }
}

sealed class AnimalInput {
    abstract val name: String
}

data class CatInput(
    override val name: String,
    val catProperty: Int,
) : AnimalInput()

data class DogInput(
    override val name: String,
    val dogProperty: Float,
) : AnimalInput()

sealed class AnimalOutput {
    abstract val name: String
}

data class CatOutput(
    override val name: String,
    val catProperty: Int,
) : AnimalOutput()

data class DogOutput(
    override val name: String,
    val dogProperty: Float,
) : AnimalOutput()
```

In my old java project, this corresponding implementation works as expected:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")
interface AnimalMapper {

    DogOutput mapToDogOutput(DogInput dogInput);

    CatOutput mapToCatOutput(CatInput catInput);

    default AnimalOutput mapToAnimalOutput(AnimalInput animalInput) {
        if (animalInput instanceof DogInput) {
            return mapToDogOutput((DogInput) animalInput);
        }
        if (animalInput instanceof CatInput) {
            return mapToCatOutput((CatInput) animalInput);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported animal type");
    }
}

public abstract class AnimalInput {
    public String name;
}

public abstract class CatInput extends AnimalInput {
    public String name;
    public int catProperty;
}

public abstract class DogInput extends AnimalInput {
    public String name;
    public float dogProperty;
}

public abstract class AnimalOutput {
    public String name;
}

public abstract class CatOutput extends AnimalOutput {
    public String name;
    public int catProperty;
}

public abstract class DogOutput extends AnimalOutput {
    public String name;
    public float dogProperty;
}
```

I'm using the following dependency versions:

- mapstructVersion: 1.4.2.Final
- kotlinVersion: 1.5.21 (jvmTarget 16)

Anyone have an idea, how to fix this issue in my Kotlin project?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working in Kotlin is due to the fact that the generated code by Kotlin marks the `mapToAnimalOutput` method as an abstract method.

You'll need to use `@JvmDefault` on that method in order for Kotlin to generate the correct modifiers for the method.